# PyMongo/MongoDB - Geospatial Query for both Origin and Destination LatLon

Tags: python, mongodb, geospatial, pymongo

Using PyMongo in Python, I'm attempting to do a GeoSpatial query for both the Origin LatLon and the Destination LatLon within a set radius, and print the first result. What I have below is what I thought it would of been, but I get an error. What's the proper way to go about this?

**Code:**

```
origin = [float(44.8697193), float(13.8414046)]
dest = [float(48.1367203), float(11.576754)]
query = db.collection.find({'origLatLng': {'$within': {'$center': [origin,.75]}}}, {'destLatLng': {'$within': {'$center': [dest,.75]}}})[0]
print query
```

**Error:**

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: Unsupported projection option: $within
```

Now if I just search for the origin, without the dest, I don't get the error concerning *'$within'*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's something wrong with your query syntax. You actually have two query documents, one for `origLatLng` and another for `destLatLng`. I think you mean to do this:

```
query = db.collection.find({'start': {'$within': {'$center': [origin,.75]}}, 'end': {'$within': {'$center': [dest,.75]}}})[0]
```

Your second query document is being interpreted as doing a projection, which is why you're getting an OperationFailure with an "Unsupported projection option: `$within`".

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the actual MongoDB version that you're using but `$within` was deprecated and now you should be using `$geoWithin`:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/geoWithin/

Also see the above link for further options. I'm not an expert on Python but I hope that `$geoWithin` will solve your problem.